# A part of a switch statement from my reducer works in an unexpected way, please take a look to the code

Tags: redux, react-redux, reducers

I have this code in my reducer ( it behavior was discovered in the process of creating )

```
case 'UPDATE_GOAL':
   state.goals.map( el => {
      if (el.id === id*1) {el.goal = updatedGoal.goal}
   })
   return state
```

it works properly, but I am confused. map() function should return a new array then I must update state with a new array, but in this case, seems it returns new array directly to the object and the state update in a "wrong way"

please help me understand how it works

Comment: in this case, the state becomes mutable. I got this, and this code will be refactored. but my question about map() and it's behavior in this case still not clear for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the map returns a new array. But problem is that you are mutating objects which are in this array, you cannot modify your `el` with `el.goal = updatedGoal.goal`.

When you are using `map` function, almost always you should just return something form it and do not modify the underlying items directly.

Try to do this exactly according the [redux recipes](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-an-item-in-an-array):

```js
case 'UPDATE_GOAL':
    return state.goals.map((el, index) => {
        if (el.id !== id*1) {
            // This isn't the item we care about - keep it as-is
            return el
        }

        // Otherwise, this is the one we want - return an updated value
        return {
            ...el,
            goal: updatedGoal.goal
        }
    })
```

Comment: thank you, I got it, but my question is - why map() function mutate object in this case

Comment: Sorry, but maybe you did not "got it" yet. `map` returns a new array, items of this array are those you return from the `map` callback function. You are not returning nothing from the callback function, that's the first problem of your code. (you are not using the result of map call either). Hence your map will not return anything (maybe array of `undefined` items, I did not checked it).The reason why your map mutates your array is simple. The argument of the map callback is an original item from your original state. And you mutate this original item directly with `el.goal = updatedGoal.goal`.